# Strange behavior of VHDL if statement

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I was stucked in a strange problem with VHDL if statement when I was working on my project. Although I fixed it, I still don't understand why it happened. I stimulated my code using ModelSPIM. Before I changed the code, I expected `rd <= inst (20 downto 16);` when `RegDst = '1'`, but it gave me `rd <= inst (15 downto 11);`. I have checked `RegDst` was really equal to `0`, but it gave me the wrong assignment. After I changed the code, everythings became normal. What is the difference between them ?

Before:

```
fetch: process(inst)
begin
if( inst = x"0000_0000" ) then -- end of program
    endRun <= '1';
else
    endRun <= '0';
    opcode <= inst (31 downto 26);
    rs <= inst (25 downto 21);
    rt <= inst (20 downto 16);
    if( RegDst = '1' ) then
       rd <= inst (15 downto 11);
    else
       rd <= inst (20 downto 16);
    end if;
    funct <= inst (5 downto 0);
    offset <= inst (15 downto 0);
    jsec <= inst (25 downto 0);
end if;
end process fetch;
```

After:

```
fetch: process(inst)
begin
if( inst = x"0000_0000" ) then -- end of program
    endRun <= '1';
else
    endRun <= '0';
    opcode <= inst (31 downto 26);
    rs <= inst (25 downto 21);
    rt <= inst (20 downto 16);
    funct <= inst (5 downto 0);
    offset <= inst (15 downto 0);
    jsec <= inst (25 downto 0);
end if;
end process fetch;      
   rd <= inst (15 downto 11) when (RegDst = '1') else
      inst(20 downto 16); -- RegDst mux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with your **sensitivity list**. The sensitivity list is the list of signal in the parentheses after process. A process is executed when an event occurs on any signal in it's sensitivity list.

In your case, only *inst* was in your sensitivity list. Thus, when *regDst* would change from '0' to '1', the process would not be executed (if *inst* didn't change) and *rd* would not update.

In your second approach, the statement is not in a process, thus is not affected by sensitivity list (to be exact, all signals involved in an out of process statement are considered it it's sensitivity list). Should you add *redDst* in the sensitivity list, you would have the same results:

```
process(inst, regDst)
```

Note that missing signals in sensitivity list is a very common source of mismatch between simulation and implementation since all tools I know ignore them for implementation. If you use VHDL-2008, you can use the keyword *all* in your sensitivity list, which implies exactly what you think.